# Question re-opened but no post "Edit History" link shown

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, revision-history

When edits are made to a post, it shows who has last edited a post.

However, when a question that has never been edited before gets re-opened, there is no link to the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31304650/revisions) (because I want to view who has closed/re-opened the question previously).

Example question that has been previously closed and re-opened: [Find a div by color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31304650/find-div-by-color/revisions)

Could this feature be added in?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69652/revision-history-missing-on-closed-and-re-opened-questions -> `status-bydesign`?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168766/204869

Comment: Seems like second link you posted confirms it as by-design. Thanks :)

Comment: Revisiting this many years later, I have added revision & timeline links to posts in my [Sticky Post Headers & Question Table of Contents](https://stackapps.com/q/7994/9011) userscript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Paraphrasing Shog9 from [Show link to revision history when there are revisions but no edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168765/show-link-to-revision-history-when-there-are-revisions-but-no-edits/168766#168766):

> Most readers don't care about such changes, so we only show the "edited link" for posts with actual textual or tag changes.

Comment: He might want to be a bit more discerning, and show it for logged-in users.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.