# I voted to close a question as duplicate then my vote and the comment disappeared

Tags: support

**Where's my vote to close as duplicate?**

I voted to close this question ten minutes ago:

[How to input a default .txt file into an iPhone through xCode in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976958/how-to-input-a-default-txt-file-into-an-iphone-through-xcode-in-swift)

as a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27206176/where-to-place-a-txt-file-and-read-from-it-in-a-ios-project?rq=1).

A few minutes later I come back and the vote has disappeared.

It doesn't show as disputed or declined, it's just not there anymore.

The autogenerated comment has also disappeared.

I can still see this, though:

[image]

What happened? If a moderator canceled my actions, shouldn't the post revisions or my `profile/all actions` tab show something?

Or did I make a misclick somewhere?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can see what happened in https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33976958/revisions

1. You voted to close as duplicate.
2. A gold badge user used his dupehammer to close the question as duplicate.
3. The gold user changed his mind and used the dupehammer to reopen the question.

[image]

It's tricky sometimes to notice things like this, because closure and reopening don't produce a link to the revision list, even if they are listed there. If you want to see the revisions of a post which doesn't have the revisions link, you can right-click "edit" link, open it in a new tab and replace "edit" at the end of the url with "revisions".

Comment: @EricD.: The "trace" is in the revision history. That's the usual place for questions that have at some time been closed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I looked for this, of course, and I see nothing: I can't go to the revisions. The direct link given by Oriol works, though.

Comment: Gold badge dupehammered, but the accepted answer quotes the link I was using as duplicate. Oh well... let's move on. Thank you for your answer,  Oriol.

Comment: @EricD.: Oh, you mean you looked *at the question* and didn't see a link to the revision history. That's a [known issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298951/question-re-opened-but-no-post-edit-history-link-shown).

Comment: @NathanTuggy Yes, sorry I wasn't clear. :/ Thanks for the link.